# Rolling join on data.table with duplicate keys

Tags: r, join, data.table

I'm trying to understand `rolling joins` in `data.table`. The data to reproduce this is given at the end.

Given a data.table of transactions at an airport, at a given time:

```
> dt
   t_id airport thisTime
1:    1       a      5.1
2:    3       a      5.1
3:    2       a      6.2
```

(note `t_ids` 1 & 3 have the same airport and time)

and a lookup table of flights departing from airports:

```
> dt_lookup
   f_id airport thisTime
1:    1       a        6
2:    2       a        6
3:    1       b        7
4:    1       c        8
5:    2       d        7
6:    1       d        9
7:    2       e        8

> tables()
     NAME      NROW NCOL MB COLS                  KEY             
[1,] dt           3    3  1 t_id,airport,thisTime airport,thisTime
[2,] dt_lookup    7    3  1 f_id,airport,thisTime airport,thisTime
```

I would like to match all the transactions to all the next possible flights departing from that airport, to give:

```
   t_id airport thisTime f_id
      1       a        6    1
      1       a        6    2
      3       a        6    1
      3       a        6    2
```

So I thought this would work:

```
> dt[dt_lookup, nomatch=0,roll=Inf]
   t_id airport thisTime f_id
1:    3       a        6    1
2:    3       a        6    2
```

But it hasn't returned transactions `t_id == 1`.

From [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) it says:

> Usually, there should be no duplicates in x’s key,...

However, I do have duplicates in my 'x key' (namely `airport` & `thisTime`), and can't quite see/understand what's going on to mean `t_id = 1` gets removed from the output.

Can anyone shed some light as to why `t_id = 1` is not returned, and how can I get the join to work for when I have duplicates?

**Data**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(t_id = seq(1:3),
                 airport = c("a","a","a"),
                 thisTime = c(5.1,6.2, 5.1), key=c( "airport","thisTime"))

dt_lookup <- data.table(f_id = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)),
                        airport = c("a","b","c","d",
                                 "a","d","e"),
                        thisTime = c(6,7,8,9,
                                 6,7,8), key=c("airport","thisTime"))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason that `t_id = 1` doesn't show up in the output is because a rolling join takes the row where the key-combination occurs last. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Applies to the last join column, generally a date but can be any
>   ordered variable, irregular and including gaps. If roll=TRUE and i's
>   row matches to all but the last x join column, and its value in the
>   last i join column falls in a gap (including after the last
>   observation in x for that group), then the prevailing value in x is
>   rolled forward. This operation is particularly fast using a modified
>   binary search. **The operation is also known as last observation carried
>   forward (LOCF).**

Let's consider somewhat larger datasets:

```
> DT
   t_id airport thisTime
1:    1       a      5.1
2:    4       a      5.1
3:    3       a      5.1
4:    2       d      6.2
5:    5       d      6.2

> DT_LU
   f_id airport thisTime
1:    1       a        6
2:    2       a        6
3:    2       a        8
4:    1       b        7
5:    1       c        8
6:    2       d        7
7:    1       d        9
```

When you perform a rolling join just like in your question:

```
DT[DT_LU, nomatch=0, roll=Inf]
```

you get:

> ```
>    t_id airport thisTime f_id
> 1:    3       a        6    1
> 2:    3       a        6    2
> 3:    3       a        8    2
> 4:    5       d        7    2
> 5:    5       d        9    1
> ```

As you can see, from both the key combination `a, 5.1` and `d, 6.2` the last row is used for the joined datatable. Because you use `Inf` as roll-value, all the future values are incorporated in the resulting datatable. When you use:

```
DT[DT_LU, nomatch=0, roll=1]
```

you see that only the first value in the future is included:

> ```
>    t_id airport thisTime f_id
> 1:    3       a        6    1
> 2:    3       a        6    2
> 3:    5       d        7    2
> ```

---

If you want the `f_id`'s for for all combinations of `airport` & `thisTime` where `DT$thisTime` is lower than `DT_LU$thisTime`, you can achieve that by creating a new variable (or replacing the existing `thisTime`) by means of the `ceiling` function. An example where I create a new variable `thisTime2` and then do a normal join with `DT_LU`:

```
DT[, thisTime2 := ceiling(thisTime)]
setkey(DT, airport, thisTime2)[DT_LU, nomatch=0]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    t_id airport thisTime thisTime2 f_id
> 1:    1       a      5.1         6    1
> 2:    4       a      5.1         6    1
> 3:    3       a      5.1         6    1
> 4:    1       a      5.1         6    2
> 5:    4       a      5.1         6    2
> 6:    3       a      5.1         6    2
> 7:    2       d      6.2         7    2
> 8:    5       d      6.2         7    2
> ```

Applied to the data you provided:

> ```
> > dt[, thisTime2 := ceiling(thisTime)]
> > setkey(dt, airport, thisTime2)[dt_lookup, nomatch=0]
>
>    t_id airport thisTime thisTime2 f_id
> 1:    1       a      5.1         6    1
> 2:    3       a      5.1         6    1
> 3:    1       a      5.1         6    2
> 4:    3       a      5.1         6    2
> ```

---

When you want to include al the future values instead of only the first one, you need a somewhat different approach for which you will need the `i.col` functionality (which is not documented yet):

**1**: First set the key to only the `airport` columns:

```
setkey(DT, airport)
setkey(DT_LU, airport)
```

**2**: Use the `i.col` functionality (which is not documented yet) in `j` to get what you want as follows:

```
DT1 <- DT_LU[DT, .(tid = i.t_id,
                   tTime = i.thisTime,
                   fTime = thisTime[i.thisTime < thisTime],
                   fid = f_id[i.thisTime < thisTime]),
             by=.EACHI]
```

this gives you:

> ```
> > DT1
>     airport tid tTime fTime fid
>  1:       a   1   5.1     6   1
>  2:       a   1   5.1     6   2
>  3:       a   1   5.1     8   2
>  4:       a   4   5.1     6   1
>  5:       a   4   5.1     6   2
>  6:       a   4   5.1     8   2
>  7:       a   3   5.1     6   1
>  8:       a   3   5.1     6   2
>  9:       a   3   5.1     8   2
> 10:       d   2   6.2     7   2
> 11:       d   2   6.2     9   1
> 12:       d   5   6.2     7   2
> 13:       d   5   6.2     9   1
> ```

Some explanation: In case when you are joining two datatables where the same columnnames are used, you can refer to the columns of the datatable in `i` by preceding the columnnames with `i.`. Now it's possible to compare `thisTime` from `DT` with `thisTime` from `DT_LU`. With `by = .EACHI` you assure that all combinations for with the condition holds are included in the resulting datatable.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same with:

```
DT2 <- DT_LU[DT, .(airport=i.airport,
                   tid=i.t_id,
                   tTime=i.thisTime,
                   fTime=thisTime[i.thisTime < thisTime],
                   fid=f_id[i.thisTime < thisTime]),
             allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

which gives the same result:

```
> identical(DT1, DT2)
[1] TRUE
```

When you only want to include future values within a certain boundary, you can use:

```
DT1 <- DT_LU[DT, 
             {
               idx = i.thisTime < thisTime & thisTime - i.thisTime < 2
               .(tid  = i.t_id,
                 tTime = i.thisTime,
                 fTime = thisTime[idx],
                 fid = f_id[idx])
               },
             by=.EACHI]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DT1
>    airport tid tTime fTime fid
> 1:       a   1   5.1     6   1
> 2:       a   1   5.1     6   2
> 3:       a   4   5.1     6   1
> 4:       a   4   5.1     6   2
> 5:       a   3   5.1     6   1
> 6:       a   3   5.1     6   2
> 7:       d   2   6.2     7   2
> 8:       d   5   6.2     7   2
> ```

When you compare that to the previous result, you see that now the rows 3, 6, 9, 10 and 12 have been removed.

---

**Data:**

```
DT <- data.table(t_id = c(1,4,2,3,5),
                 airport = c("a","a","d","a","d"),
                 thisTime = c(5.1, 5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 6.2),
                 key=c("airport","thisTime"))

DT_LU <- data.table(f_id = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)),
                    airport = c("a","b","c","d","a","d","e"),
                    thisTime = c(6,7,8,9,6,7,8),
                    key=c("airport","thisTime"))
```

Comment: Great explanation - "a rolling join takes the row where the key-combination occurs last" - was the key to my understanding thanks.

Comment: And your `ceiling` example works well in this situation, but I expect it won't work when the `dt$thisTime2` value is more than `1` time unit away from the `dt_lookup$thisTime` value it's trying to match to, so I may have to come up with an alternative?

Comment: I think this might be one of the best SO answers I've seen! thanks for taking the time with it and introducing me to a few new techniques.

Comment: @tospig This might be of interest: I asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034222/odd-behavior-when-joining-with-multiple-conditions) about some oddity which I ran into when solving your problem.

Comment: @tospig Based on the [answer on my question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32034604/2204410), I have updated my answer again. The improvements will prevent you from running into the same oddities as I have run into.