# selecting records within a range in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that I am trying to filter in dplyr, but I can't seem to get the code right to get it done. Here are the two data sets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"),
                  Position = c(5 ,12, 20, 25, 50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df1
  Chromosome Position
1       chr1        5
2       chr1       12
3       chr2       20
4       chr3       25
5       chr4       50

df2 <- data.frame(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr3"), From = c(1, 20),
                  To = c(10, 80),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df2
  Chromosome From To
1       chr1    1 10
2       chr3   20 80
```

What I would like to do is select those rows from the first table where the chromosome numbers are identical between the tables and the position is contained between the "From" and the "To" in the second table. So the output here would be:

```
  Chromosome Position
1       chr1        5
2       chr3       25
```

Any suggestions on how to write this in R? In particular I'd love to use dplyr functions, but not required.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't think so.. I think we're talking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25655497/559784).. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(Position > From, Position < To ) %>%
  select(-From, -To)

  Chromosome Position
1       chr1        5
2       chr3       25
```

This assumes no duplicated values of `Chromosome` in your data.frame with From and To.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everyone. There are definitely duplicated values of Chromosome, but if I use inner_join instead of left_join above it seems to work just fine. The size of the intermediate file is enormous. I'll also play around with some of the data.table "foverlap" functions on the referenced thread above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to `data.table` one method would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key="Chromosome")
setDT(df2, key="Chromosome")

df1[ df2,  { idx = i.From <= Position & Position <= i.To
              .(Position = Position[idx])
          },
     by=.EACHI
     ]

#   Chromosome Position
#1:       chr1        5
#2:       chr3       25
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011937/4002530) to a previous question of mine