# R - Unexpected output for rolling join with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use the rolling join from the data.table package but I can't seem to get the output I want.

My data is:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('    datetime   price
"2016-05-01 18:58:49.078" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:49.078" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:49.078" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:49.078" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:51.085" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:53.703" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:53.757" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:53.757" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:53.757" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:58:54.155" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 18:59:07.013" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:59:07.013" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:59:07.015" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:59:08.604" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:59:31.500" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 18:59:40.723" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 18:59:40.723" 2059.25
"2016-05-01 19:00:00.003" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:00.003" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:00.003" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:00.359" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:00.381" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:02.390" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:04.355" 2059.50
"2016-05-01 19:00:06.230" 2059.50', header = T)

dt$datetime <- as.POSIXct(dt$datetime)
```

and I want to know the most recent price at each minute:

```
dt_minutes <- data.table(datetime = c(as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 18:59:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 19:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 19:01:00")))

> dt_minutes
              datetime
1: 2016-05-01 18:59:00
2: 2016-05-01 19:00:00
3: 2016-05-01 19:01:00
```

and the output I get is:

```
> dt[dt_minutes, roll = TRUE, on = "datetime"]
              datetime  price
1: 2016-05-01 18:59:00 2059.5
2: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5
3: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5
4: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5
5: 2016-05-01 19:01:00 2059.5
```

but I expect:

```
1: 2016-05-01 18:59:00 2059.5
2: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.25
5: 2016-05-01 19:01:00 2059.5
```

Does anyone know why I am getting repeated "2016-05-01 19:00:00" in my output and the wrong price for that time?

Comment: is it because you have duplicates in your `dt`? try it with `unique(dt)[dt_minutes, roll = TRUE, on = "datetime" ]`

Comment: It seems so but the middle price is still wrong.

I feel that the `"2016-05-01 19:00:00.003" 2059.50` row is being counted for the `"2016-05-01 19:00:00"` minute even though it is after that time.

Comment: R seems to be giving me lots of headaches with milliseconds.

Comment: This is an issue with how data.table merges floating-point numbers (which is what your POSIX thing with milliseconds is stored as). If you run `setNumericRounding(0)` beforehand, you'll get the result you want, but may find other weird side effects.https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Frank's answer in the comment, if you run `setNumericRounding(0)` you will achieve the results you want.

Note also that you can store a copy of your `datetime` variable in `dt` to see which time it rolled *from* to match the key in your `dt_minutes`, which also should make clear how it was rounding in the first place as well:

```
dt[ , dt_datetime_orig := datetime]  # make a copy of time variable
setNumericRounding(2)  # 2 is the default
dt[dt_minutes, roll = TRUE, on = "datetime"]
##               datetime  price    dt_datetime_orig
## 1: 2016-05-01 18:59:00 2059.5 2016-05-01 18:58:54
## 2: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5 2016-05-01 19:00:00
## 3: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5 2016-05-01 19:00:00
## 4: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.5 2016-05-01 19:00:00
## 5: 2016-05-01 19:01:00 2059.5 2016-05-01 19:00:06
setNumericRounding(0)
dt[dt_minutes, roll = TRUE, on = "datetime"]
##               datetime   price    dt_datetime_orig
## 1: 2016-05-01 18:59:00 2059.50 2016-05-01 18:58:54
## 2: 2016-05-01 19:00:00 2059.25 2016-05-01 18:59:40
## 3: 2016-05-01 19:01:00 2059.50 2016-05-01 19:00:06
```