# Find strings that contain a sequence of characters regardless of the order in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, pattern-matching, permutation

I have a dataframe(df)

```
    V1    V2
1 "BCC"  Yes
2 "ABB"  Yes
```

I want to find all the strings that contain a certain sequence of characters, regardless of the order.
For example if I have the string "CBC" or "CCB" I would like to get

```
    V1    V2
1 "BCC"  Yes
```

I've tried with grep, but It only finds the matching patterns

```
>df[grep("CBC", df$V1),]
1  V1   V2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

>df[grep("BCC", df$V1),]
   V1   V2
1 "BCC" Yes
```

Comment: will they always be strings of 3-letters?

Comment: @SymbolixAU yup, only 3 letters

Comment: If the sequence to match is BBC do you require there to be at least two "B"s?

Comment: Try just `df[grepl("^[CB]+$", df$V1),]` where `^[CB]+$` matches any string containing 1 or more `B` or/and `C` chars. If you want to only match 3-char strings, replace `+` with `{3}`.

Comment: @Dason yes. I have to match all the possible 3-letter strings that are in another Dataframe. So it should be also “BAB”, “BBA” and so on. This dataframe is like a lookup table

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If you have another dataset and you want to compare with the all the elements from that dataset, it should be included in the question

Answer (score 4):

We can create a logical index by splitting the column

```
i1 <- sapply(strsplit(df$V1, ""), function(x) all(c("B", "C") %in% x))
df[i1, , drop = FALSE]
#   V1  V2
#1 BCC Yes
```

---

if we have two datasets and one is a lookup table ('df2'), then split the column into characters,`paste` the `sort`ed elements, and use `%in%` to create the logical `vector` for filtering the rows

```
v1n <- sapply(strsplit(df1$v1, ""), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))
v1l <- sapply(strsplit(df2$v1, ""), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))
df1[v1n %in% v1l, , drop = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("BCC", "CAB" , "ABB", "CBC", "CCB", "BAB", "CDB"),
     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c("CBC", "ABB"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Thanks.  Have you looked into any courses offered by datacamp, udemy, udactiy etc.  Books can help a lot in understanding, but practise is the key.  I didn't take any course in R, but I took many courses to learn other languages.  My take is that you need constant practice beyond what the course offers

Comment: Yeah, I am actually reading books(online only) but expertise that you have(truly bottom of my heart I am saying I become fan of you) that will come by practice and moreover I didn't see these many examples apart from basics, I will try my BEST to do practice, thanks for suggestion sir.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Sure, It comes from practise.  Suppose, if I start with "awk' on day one and compare it with you, I would be feeling the same thing as you are feeling now.

Comment: To be honest not comparing :) but made you an ideal so that we could reach somewhere(like a GURU kinda) :) what do you say(R guru) :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Sorry, I should have used a different word.  I meant that you are far ahead on awk than me because I don't practise it.  I do understand that learning a language to understand all the quirks and behaviors of functions, takes some time. I would advise to spend at least an hour or half an hour every day and be consistent instead of doing things for 24 hours and then stop

Comment: Sure sir, I got it. Thanks for your cool advice will try my best to keep the consistency and keep learning from you too, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you mention a lookup table. If this is the case, an approach could be to join both sets together, then use the [regex by Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092283/find-strings-that-contain-a-sequence-of-characters-regardless-of-the-order-in-r#comment89172881_51092283) to indicate which are valid

As I'm joining data sets I'm going to use `data.table`

#### Method 1: Join everything

```
library(data.table)

## dummy data, and a lookup table
dt <- data.frame(V1 = c("BCC", "ABB"))
dt_lookup <- data.frame(V1 = c("CBC","BAB", "CCB"))

## convert to data.table
setDT(dt); setDT(dt_lookup)

## add some indexes to keep track of rows from each dt
dt[, idx := .I]
dt_lookup[, l_idx := .I]

## create a column to join on
dt[, key := 1L]
dt_lookup[, key := 1L]

## join EVERYTHING
dt <- dt[
    dt_lookup
    , on = "key"
    , allow.cartesian = T
]

#regex
dt[
    , valid := grepl(paste0("^[",i.V1,"]+$"), V1)
    , by = 1:nrow(dt)
]

#     V1 idx key i.V1 l_idx valid
# 1: BCC   1   1  CBC     1  TRUE
# 2: ABB   2   1  CBC     1 FALSE
# 3: BCC   1   1  BAB     2 FALSE
# 4: ABB   2   1  BAB     2  TRUE
# 5: BCC   1   1  CCB     3  TRUE
# 6: ABB   2   1  CCB     3 FALSE
```

---

### Method 2: EACHI join

A slightly more memory-efficient approach might be to use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011937/5977215) by Jaap as it avoids the 'join everything' step, and in stead joins it 'by each i' (row) at a time.

```
dt_lookup[
    dt, 
    {
        valid = grepl(paste0("^[",i.V1,"]+$"), V1)
        .(
            V1 = V1[valid]
            , idx = i.idx
            , match = i.V1
            , l_idx = l_idx[valid]
            )
    }
    , on = "key"
    , by = .EACHI
]

#    key  V1 idx match l_idx
# 1:   1 CBC   1   BCC     1
# 2:   1 CCB   1   BCC     3
# 3:   1 BAB   2   ABB     2
```

Comment: Great answer. I like that you can see whether each string matches, and it's easy to see whether any or all of them match with `dt[, Reduce(\`|\`, valid), V1]` and `dt[, Reduce(\`&\`, valid), V1]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using `sapply`, `table`, and `identical`.

```
# construct a named vector of integers with names in 
# alphabetical order: your match
myVal <- c("B"=1L, "C"=2L)
# run through character variable, perform check
sapply(strsplit(dat$V1, ""), function(x) identical(c(table(x)), myVal))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Two key points related to the use of `identical` and the output of `table`:

1. the match vector, myVal must be integer.
2. You want to order the match vector alphabetically, yough you can do this ahead of time, you can also do it after the fact with `order`, `names`, and `[`.

Also, not that I wrapped the output of `table` in `c` to strip off undesired attributes, while maintaining the names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringi::stri_count_regex` to see if the number of occurrences in your string matches the `table` of `strsplit(str_to_find, '')`. The last `reduce("|")` means it's checking if there are any matches, so change `|` to `&` if you want to check if it matches all the strings in `to.find`.

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(a = replicate(20, paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 3, T), collapse = ''))
                 , stringsAsFactors = F)

to.find <- c("CBB", "CCB")
to.find <- strsplit(to.find, '')

library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
df$b <- 
sapply(df$a, function(x){
         lapply(to.find, function(y){
           imap(table(y), ~ .x == stri_count_regex(x, .y)) %>% 
             reduce(`&`)}) %>% 
          reduce(`|`)})

df

# a     b
# 1  CAB FALSE
# 2  BCA FALSE
# 3  CCB  TRUE
# 4  BAA FALSE
# 5  ACB FALSE
# 6  CBC  TRUE
# 7  CBC  TRUE
# 8  CAB FALSE
# 9  AAB FALSE
# 10 ABC FALSE
# 11 BBB FALSE
# 12 BAC FALSE
# 13 CCA FALSE
# 14 CBC  TRUE
# 15 BCB  TRUE
# 16 BCA FALSE
# 17 BCC  TRUE
# 18 BCB  TRUE
# 19 AAA FALSE
# 20 ABB FALSE
# 19 AAA FALSE
# 20 ABB FALSE
```

You can also do it all with `map`, but that's harder to read

```
df$b <- 
df$a %>% 
  map(~{x <- .x
        map(to.find, 
            ~imap(table(.x), ~ .x == stri_count_regex(x, .y)) %>% 
              reduce(`&`)) %>% 
          reduce(`|`)})
```