# Inner join using an inequality expression

Tags: r, data.table

**Background**

(Not required for the question, but may be useful to read)

[Rolling join on data.table with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32007115/4002530)

[Odd behaviour when joining with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32034222/4002530)

**Data**

```
library(data.table)   ## using version 1.9.6
## arrival timetable
dt_arrive <- structure(list(txn_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), place = c("place_a", 
"place_a", "place_a", "place_a", "place_a"), arrival_minutes = c(515, 
534, 547, 561, 581), journey_id = 1:5), .Names = c("txn_id", 
"place", "arrival_minutes", "journey_id"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), sorted = c("txn_id", 
"place"))

## departure timetable
dt_depart <- structure(list(txn_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), place = c("place_a", 
"place_a", "place_a", "place_a"), arrival_minutes = c(489, 507, 
519, 543), journey_id = 10:13), .Names = c("txn_id", "place", 
"arrival_minutes", "journey_id"), sorted = c("txn_id", "place"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

> dt_arrive
   txn_id   place arrival_minutes journey_id
1:      1 place_a             515          1
2:      1 place_a             534          2
3:      1 place_a             547          3
4:      1 place_a             561          4
5:      1 place_a             581          5

> dt_depart
   txn_id   place arrival_minutes journey_id
1:      1 place_a             489         10
2:      1 place_a             507         11
3:      1 place_a             519         12
4:      1 place_a             543         13
```

**Question**

I would like to join the arrivals to the departures for **only** those `dt_depart$journey_id` that occur **after** `dt_arrive$journey_id` in terms of `arrival_minutes` (i.e. an inner join on `txn_id` & `place`)

For example, the output I would like is:

```
   txn_id   place journey_in_id journey_out_id journey_place_arrive journey_place_depart
      1     place_a          1             12                  515                  519
      1     place_a          1             13                  515                  543
      1     place_a          2             13                  534                  543
```

**Attempts**

Using the method from the two linked questions I have constructed

```
setkey(dt_arrive, txn_id, place)
setkey(dt_depart, txn_id, place)

dt_join <- dt_arrive[dt_depart,
            {
              idx = (i.arrival_minutes > arrival_minutes)
              .(journey_in_id = journey_id[idx],
                journey_out_id = i.journey_id,
                journey_place_arrive = arrival_minutes[idx],
                journey_place_depart = i.arrival_minutes
              )
            },
            by=.EACHI]
```

But this gives everything from `dt_depart`, so includes `NA`s in the result - which suggests a 'right join':

```
   txn_id   place journey_in_id journey_out_id journey_place_arrive journey_place_depart
1:      1  place_a         NA             10                   NA                  489
2:      1  place_a         NA             11                   NA                  507
3:      1  place_a          1             12                  515                  519
4:      1  place_a          1             13                  515                  543
5:      1  place_a          2             13                  534                  543
```

I've tried using `nomatch=0` to force it to 'inner join', but this hasn't worked.

I can use `complete.cases` to remove the `NA` rows, but I was wondering if there's a way of doing this within the query itself?

Comment: Why does your "For example" output exclude the 534 to 543 line?

Comment: @Frank typo - it should be included.

Comment: @Frank Have you deleted your answer? I thought it included the three lines required anyway?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought that it was wrong (as in, would give wrong results in a different case from your example), but looking again, have changed my mind and undeleted.

Comment: @Frank, great, thanks - I'll take a look

Comment: We're looking into non-equi joins extensions for data tables. Will update this post once done.

Comment: @Arun - perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the unclever approach: take the cross/Cartesian join, and then filter.

```
merge(dt_arrive, dt_depart, allow.cartesian=TRUE)[arrival_minutes.y > arrival_minutes.x]

#    txn_id   place arrival_minutes.x journey_id.x arrival_minutes.y journey_id.y
# 1:      1 place_a               515            1               519           12
# 2:      1 place_a               515            1               543           13
# 3:      1 place_a               534            2               543           13
```

By taking the Cartesian join, we're liable to eat up a lot of memory.

Comment: I read to quickly and thought you said "here's the clever approach". I thought "no, that's not clever!", and then realized my mistake. Clever or not, it's the only working answer so far :)

Comment: This method benchmarks quicker than my method. I now need to test how well it scales to my actual data.

Comment: playing about with another data.table variation (inspired by this answer) `dt_arrive[dt_depart, nomatch=0, allow.cartesian=TRUE][i.arrival_minutes > arrival_minutes]` seems quicker still.

Comment: @tospig I'm curious, what does `nomatch` change here? Have you found that either sort of merge (since yours is also a merge) scales well? Generally, I've found that cross/Cartesian operations (including the `outer` function) bring my computer to a standstill routinely.

Comment: I've not attempted this on my actual data yet, and I don't know enough about the guts of data.table to explain what `nomatch` is doing, I just use it whenever I need an inner-join. In the past I've not had any issues with cartesian joins slowing my computer though - but I may not have had enough data to test it..

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution is to use `foverlaps` by making some arbitrary interval columns

```
setDT(dt_arrive)
setDT(dt_depart)

dt_arrive[, `:=`(arrival_minutes_copy = arrival_minutes)]
## reorder columns
dt_arrive <- dt_arrive[, .(txn_id, place, journey_id, arrival_minutes, arrival_minutes_copy)]

dt_depart[, `:=`(arrival_minutes_copy = min(arrival_minutes))]
## reorder columns
dt_depart <- dt_depart[, .(txn_id, place, journey_id, arrival_minutes_copy, arrival_minutes)]

setkey(dt_arrive, arrival_minutes, arrival_minutes_copy)
setkey(dt_depart, arrival_minutes_copy, arrival_minutes)

foverlaps(dt_arrive, 
          dt_depart,
          type = "within",
          nomatch=0L)


#      place txn_id journey_id arrival_minutes_copy arrival_minutes i.txn_id i.journey_id i.arrival_minutes i.arrival_minutes_copy
# 1: place_a      1         12                  489             519        1            1               515                    515
# 2: place_a      1         13                  489             543        1            1               515                    515
# 3: place_a      1         13                  489             543        1            2               534                    534
```

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)

fun_foverlap <- function(dt_a, dt_d){
    dt <- foverlaps(dt_a, 
                                    dt_d,
                        type = "within",
                        nomatch=0L)
    return(dt)
}

fun_merge <- function(dt_a, dt_d){
    dt <- merge(dt_a, dt_d, allow.cartesian=TRUE)[arrival_minutes.y > arrival_minutes.x]
    return(dt)
}

fun_nomatch <- function(dt_a, dt_d){
    dt <- dt_a[dt_d, nomatch=0, allow.cartesian=TRUE][i.arrival_minutes > arrival_minutes]
    return(dt)
}

microbenchmark(fun_foverlap(dt_arrive_foverlap, dt_depart_foverlap),
                             fun_merge(dt_arrive_merge, dt_depart_merge),
                             fun_nomatch(dt_arrive_nomatch, dt_depart_nomatch))

# Unit: microseconds
                                                  expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
 # fun_foverlap(dt_arrive_foverlap, dt_depart_foverlap) 3538.189 3717.077 3967.6648 3872.586 4006.7205 5812.355   100   c
 #          fun_merge(dt_arrive_merge, dt_depart_merge)  883.697  925.655  980.4159  942.877  967.9745 2223.147   100  b 
 #    fun_nomatch(dt_arrive_nomatch, dt_depart_nomatch)  593.082  625.471  682.8975  643.034  665.4125 2077.748   100 a
```